# How to post back data from client o server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I am using asp.net post back method to send data from jQuery MessageBox to server. Is this correct way to send data to server without refreshing whole web page? What would be other alternatives?

default.aspx client code

```
function confirmDelete(id) {
    var msg = 'Are you sure you want to delete user?';

    $.msgbox(msg, {
        type: "confirm",
        buttons: [
                { type: "submit", value: "Yes" },
                { type: "submit", value: "No" }
                ]
    },
    function (res) {
        var answ = res;
        if (answ == 'Yes') {
            __doPostBack('<%=upPanel.UniqueID%>$Delete', id);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

default.aspx.cs server code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
                {
                    var sourceId = Request.Form.Get(postEventSourceID);
                    var argumentId = Request.Form.Get(postEventArgumentID);
                    if (sourceId.Contains("Delete"))
                    {
                        var id = Helpers.GetInt(argumentId);
                        DeleteUser(id);
                    }
                }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to partially refresh the page. `__doPostBack` will submit the form and refresh the whole page.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "urlOfThePage",
   data: {},
   success: function(response){
   }
});
```